# Scroll to particular Item in FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have implemented a notifications and would like to scroll to particular post on press of these notifications. So onload of another screen that post will be visible in the flatlist.

It is a kind of functionality FB have. if someone commented you will get the notification and on clicking of that notification it will directly take you to that particular comment.

I have `id's` in the notification which is present in the `Flatlist` item.

How can i achieve same behavior in React Native.

Comment: Have you tried using FlatList's scrollToIndex? https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist.html#scrolltoindex

Answer (score 5):

If You have an id of a particular notification that is present in the flat list you can find the index of that id and scroll the flat list after one millisecond once the screen is redirected. code for finding the index is below.

```
 let index = (list as Array<Object>).findIndex(item => item.id === 25)
 flatlist?.current.scrollToIndex({ animated: true, index: index })
```

Comment: How to highlight that index view in react native flatlist